# Adding Custom Taxonomy Archive Link to Nav Menu Shows Up As (Invalid)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus

I have a custom post type "packages" with a taxonomy "Celebrations" that has a few terms in it.

When I try to add a link to my wp nav menu through **Appearance > Menus** and choosing the term I want from the Celebrations meta box, the item shows up red with a title "(Invalid)".

See here for what I'm seeing: http://screencast.com/t/cyGF0cJU8

Has anyone else had this problem before?

I used Custom Post Type UI to register the post type and taxonomies originally with no other problems.  After this happened, I tried disabling that plugin and registering them manually, but to no avail.

I've taken a look at the wp core to see what makes this come up and this is what I found:
includes/nav-menu.php L595 in [wp_setup_nav_menu_item()](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_setup_nav_menu_item/)

```
elseif ( 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type ) {
            $object = get_taxonomy( $menu_item->object );
            if ( $object ) {
                $menu_item->type_label = $object->labels->singular_name;
            } else {
                $menu_item->type_label = $menu_item->object;
                $menu_item->_invalid = true;
            }
```

All of the meta data for the menu item appears to be there: http://screencast.com/t/0hHQmObsQAT

Any help is greatly appreciated as always!

Comment: Please try the same with a custom registration (via code) instead and see if you still can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I found the answer an another website. Taxonomies have a restriction that they cannot have uppercase characters in their name they can only have lowercase and underscore characters. that`s the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be a duplicate link that was already in the menu structure elsewhere. At least, that's my best guest why it was invalid. `:-)`

See also the [source code here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/nav-menu.php).